# codeigniter create form in view or controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

when looking in codeigniter user manual or some other open source CI base project, i realize that form are store/generate/create in views, here the example:

```
application/view/main_view.php
<?php echo form_open("/user/create");?>
  <?php echo form_input("input1",$value); ?>
  .
  .
  .
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

then load it in controller.

But in my project, i create long string that contain form + table code, when load->view, passing the hold string into that view, here are part of the code:

```
application/controller/user.php
$this->table->add_row(array("data"=>form_input("name",$value)));

$data["content"]=form_open("/user/create");
$data["content"].=$this->table->generate();
$data["content"].=form_close();

$this->load->view("main_view",$data);
```

which style are better? and why?
(PS: sorry for the broken English)

---

i using table to ensure the form layout, here come with the situation:

1. form writing in view with html table tag.
2. load html library in view(or related controller), but my view is flooding with many php code

Comment: you should write `form` at view? Why did you generate form on the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u work in a team better you use a pure html in view file and never do defining part of view in controller. but if you want to use CI form helper better you type like this :

```
<?php
   $form = form_open("/user/create");
   $form .= form_input("input1",$value) . '<br>' ;
   $form .= form_input("input2",$value) . '<br>' ;
   $form .= form_input("input3",$value) . '</br>' ;
   $form .= form_close();

   echo $form;
?>
```

it just a simple example to make shorter of code.